# Return value of a function in Erlang

Tags: erlang

What the following function will return? ok atom or Cmd?

```
function_test() ->
    Cmd = os:cmd("ls"),
    io:format("The result of ls is:~p~n", [Cmd]).
```

If it returns ok then how it should be rephrased to return Cmd while still using io:format?

Comment: Please be aware that printing a value and returning a value are two completely different things. Here you *print* the value of `Cmd` but you *return* the value returned by `io:format` which is `ok`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Erlang the last expression in your function is returned, in your case that would be the result of `io:format` which is `ok`.

To return `Cmd` you can simply make it the last expression in your function:

```
function_test() ->
    Cmd = os:cmd("ls"),
    io:format("The result of ls is:~p~n", [Cmd]),
    Cmd.
```